# How to enable text swipe on a fixed background, with Swiper?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

Currently I have a webpage served as an interactive ad in the app. You can swipe the text on the background image to get to the next text. I am using Swiper, but right now when I swipe the screen, the background image also swipes to the right, which is not what I wanted. Is there a way to make only the text swipes, but not the background, with Swiper?

Comment: #Typo:Is there a way to make it only swipe the text but not the background with swiper?

Comment: Hello OliverGY, could you put in the question some code, in order to be helped more concretely by the community? thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `overflow-x: hidden;` to the bg-image element.
However, like axel mentioned, show us some code.